# With Knockout, How to display item name from a list by id?

Tags: knockout.js

When I display a dropdown, I can have a select and let user pick. Like below

```
<select data-bind="options : $parent.items, optionsText :'name', optionsValue:'id', value : status"></select>
```

But what about I want to display the item name from a item id?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 options (I prefer #2):

(1) Make optionsValue: 'name' instead of the id. By the description of your problem this is a valid solution but I'm willing to bet that's not what you want.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/simonlevasseur/3DYh4/

```
<select data-bind="options : items, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'name', value : status"></select>
<span data-bind="text: status"></span>
```

(2) Remove the optionsValue from your bindings so that instead of just saving the id, you'll be saving the entire object.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/simonlevasseur/nCNXJ/

```
<select data-bind="options : items, optionsText: 'name', value : status"></select>
<span data-bind="text: status().name"></span>
```

(3) Search the list for the item that matches by id.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/simonlevasseur/aW23N/

```
var color = ko.utils.arrayFirst(colors, function (color) {
    return color.id === status;
});
```

Comment: thanks! seems need go for the third way, it is a field in a grid, so it is not performance good to use the first and the second way.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if i understood the question, check if this is what you want:

```
<select width="50" data-bind="foreach: items">
   <option data-bind="value: id, text:name, attr: {name: id}"></option>
</select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/david_freire/3P8m4/

Comment: thanks, I just want to display value from a list.
for example, have a list 
colorid   color
  1         Red
  2         Green
  3         Yellow

now, I have a colorid field, it has value 2, I need display Green